# Nuxt route does not accept query parameters without slash before?

Tags: amazon-s3, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have this URL that is being generated by a component I used for authentication. Unfortunately I have no control on the URL from that component package. My question is, how do I make this URL work in NUXT from:

[http://test.com/test-page?token=token_here][1]

to this:

[http://test.com/test-page/?token=token_here][1]

It works fine in my localhost but not in dev. Btw, the site is hosted in AWS S3 bucket.

Comment: I have a similar problem with you, my ops team already solve that by changing something in CloudFront settings.